# Make same status bar Color on Activity Transition

Tags: android, colors, statusbar, android-styles

When i start my Application i got the exact status bar color  as i needed but when i make activity transition my status bar color changes ,which i don't want .I am using same technique in the Previous Project ,that goes well but in here i get different.What is exact issue in this,How can this issue be solved??

**Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.municipality.mobile.patanheritage">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.Splash"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.Home" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.PopularDestination" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.PopularDestinationGridDetail" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.EventsAndFestivals" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.EventAndFestivalGridDetail" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.HireGuideForm" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.HomeStayDetailPage" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Rate_And_Review" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.Information" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.AboutHelp" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.AboutPrivacyPolicy" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.AboutTermsOfUse" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.DeveloperInfo" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.ContactMenu" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**style**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/menu_background</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/menu_text_color</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">02dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/color_yellow</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Color**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#53A9B6</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#007C88</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="windoebackground">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="menu_background">#262626</color>
    <color name="menu_text_color">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="color_yellow">#FFC000</color>
</resources>
```

**v21**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**when app start**
[image]
**on Acticvity transition**
[image]

> How can this issue be solved??

Comment: check your styles-v21 and post it here

Comment: updated please check

Comment: make your style.xml file in values folder and in values-21 folder same

Answer (score 2):

In your styles v21 please remove

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<! -- and add this -->
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

and check the output.

Comment: removing doesnot help.same result

Comment: same result mate

Comment: which version device are you using?

Comment: Checking in API level 24.

Comment: are there any other styles.xml like v24 or 23?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153321/discussion-between-ghimire-and-programming-pirate).